# Camera not following

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just started learning game dev and now I am pretty much just doing what Brackeys is doing but I am getting the error An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property "Transform.position" but he does not get the error.
Trying to make the camera follow the player.

```
public class FollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
      
       public static Transform player;
       

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       
        Transform.position = player.position;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unity is case sensitive,
`Transform.position = player.position;`  Should be
`transform.position = player.position;`

Comment: or try to make the Camera child of the player no code needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the player to follow the camera in call conditions then its better to position the camera at a distance from the player so that the view is good and make the camera a child of your player. This is same as what your above code does. About the error in your code. You just need to make it a small 't' in this line

```
transform.position = player.position;
```

But if the player rotates or jumps then you will not have the desired effect. If you need those to be taken care then you will need to write more codes or you can use Unity Cinemachine. This tutorial on [Camera follow player](https://vionixstudio.com/2019/12/02/camera-follow-script-in-unity/) covers all these topics.

Answer (score 0):

There is a diffrent between Transform and transform.
When you use Transform you refer to the class Tranform.
but when you use tranform you refer to the tranform component of the current game object.
transform is like GetComponent().
it's work the same with GameObject and gameObject.

so the answer is:
transform.position = player.position.

also some better way to make the camera follow the player is to make the camera a children of the player without code or even better way is using the cinemachine package.